# Image processing - tracking blobs of different colours

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to find the best method to track objects of different colours, on a plain background.

I have read around, and it seems that the best way to differentiate between colours is to firstly convert the image into HSV space, then threshold based on hue. However, since I am not only tracking one object, and moreover, will not know which values to threshold it by, which method is best to find the colours of these objects? Will a histogram method work, where I disregard the peak as the background takes up the majority of the pixels, then the rest of the peaks represent different colours?

Once I have found the different colours, I can threshold the image then find the contours, which outlines the object.

Is there a better way to track blobs than the methods I propose?

I have also looked at libraries such as cvBlob however I've had trouble trying to install these, so I'd rather stick to a pure OpenCV implementation.

As a side note, I am using the C++ OpenCV library.

Comment: Every object has different color, or what? If you have one color-item no need to machine learning or something like that.

Comment: Can you upload some example images?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few questions you need to ask yourself. Your question indicates you want a fairly simple tracking algorithm.  What methods have you looked at? The opencv library is a *great* place to get started.  Have you tried going through the tutorials (i.e. http://opencv-srf.blogspot.ro/2010/09/object-detection-using-color-seperation.html ) These will be stepping stones for you to build more and more complex algorithms.

- Do you need to handle occlusions (when one object goes in front of another?
- How simple is your background - is it changing at all.  If it is not changing things get much easier.
- Can objects appear spontaneously in the middle of the image frame or must objects come from the sides
- Can an objects color vary while it is moving through the frame?
- Is this a 2D or a 3D tracking problem?

In general the tracking problem is usually broken down into two parts based on the answers to the above and many other questions:

1. Object detection (current frame)
2. Object Association (from previous frame)

Making the simplest of assumptions here is a pseudo code implmentation.  Note there are many other ways to do this. Dense feature tracking, sparse features, histogram based, motion

```
#object detection (relatively easy part)
Read b = Background Image (this image needs to be read before any objects are in the scene - it can be thought of as initialization stage)
Read c = Current Image
diff = c - b > Threshold
#everywhere there is a difference indicates a part of an object
#now abstract to higher level objects based on connected components.  During occlusions you'll need to differentiate based on color, and maybe even motion if two objects are similar color
#Object association (relatively harder part)
For every object check if this object is already in your list (you'll need a distance metric here to check how similar this object is to another - based on histogram difference, feature points, motion etc...)
If in list, then add this information to the object's track
If in list, you want to consider if you need to update the object model based on the new information.  Did the object change shape/color/motion?
If not in list add it
```